# Update a drop down on a flow based on input on the same screen

Tags: lookup, flow

In a flow Is it possible to update the choices of a drop down list on the same screen as the input?

For example I have text field; enter zip code, this then filters a drop down list to allow users to select an appropriate address. It works if I add the drop down to the 2nd screen but i am hoping to put both the input box and drop down on the same screen.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out myself, and I don't believe there is - out of the box. You might be able to add it to a visualforce page and add some JavaScript to include those values, but I was never able it identify the right way to build the JS nor have I found documentation.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid code... May just write the flow in such a way it isn't too complicated for a user but it's a shame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using nothing but Flow elements, you cannot modify the input or output elements on a screen without the user clicking Previous or Next. There's no support for things like OnChange or OnSelect, or any sort of AJAX-y type actions. Flows are great for mocking a wizard or building simple interfaces, but Lightning and Visualforce are still far more capable for providing reactive user interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, the more j look at this the more I realise I really need to start reading and learning how to use apex and visualforce - I think I need to write a visualforce to use a number of web services and create a contact and a case in the same process - lots to do!